# Sucessfully queries the azure monitor service. Workspace not found. While using azuremarket place Grafana

Tags: azure, grafana, workspace

I'm trying to use azure monitor as a data source for grafana. The grafana server was created from Azure Marketplace. I used Service Principal for authentication and while clicking the 'save and test' button, I get the following error"

' 1. Successfully queried the Azure Monitor service. 2. Workspace not found. '

Can you please help me with this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a Azure App Insights resource to the monitored Subscription solved the problem. On this step the first Monitoring Workspace for the Subscription was created.
On an older Resource I had to migrate to Workspace-based Application Insights to fix the error.
It seams Grafana only works with the new Workspace-based Application Insights resources

Answer (score 0):

Follow Below steps -

1.Go to your - Log Analytics workspace->Access Control(IAM)->Add->Add Role Assignment.

Select -  Log Analytics Reader, Next select member (select you Azure AD application) & Save

2.Go back to Grafana & try to add it again, it will work

3.Also follow this steps to give access -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/manage-access

4. Step #1 also need t be followed for subscription level permission access, so go to subscription -
   Access Control(IAM)->Add->Add Role Assignment.

Select -  Log Analytics Reader, Next select member (select you Azure AD application) & Save

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was related to insufficient permissions to create Role Assignments in the Subscription where Azure Managed Grafana was initially established.

Once I obtained the necessary permissions, I set up a new instance of Azure Managed Grafana. Subsequently, Role Assignments for the "Monitoring Reader" role at the subscription scope were automatically created. With this in place, I could effortlessly assign the Managed Grafana Managed Identity to other Subscriptions.

It appears that the resource encounters problems when deployed with Managed Identity, particularly if the user lacks the requisite permissions for the subscription.